# OnClientClick event in In ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events, client-side

I'm using ASP.NET to pass a value to a JavaScript function and, for some reason I haven't been able to determine, it isn't working when I try to pass in a value from another control. Instead, it acts like there is a syntax error and it just submits back to the main form.

Does anyone know why?

Example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtToSay" runat="server" Text="Something"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSaySomething1" Text="Say Something"
OnClientClick="saySomething(<%=txtToSay.Text%>);"  /> <!-- doesn't work -->

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSaySomething1" Text="Say Something"
OnClientClick="saySomething('<%=txtToSay.Text%>');"  /> <!-- doesn't work -->

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSaySomething2" Text="Say Something"
OnClientClick="saySomething('Something');"  /> <!-- works -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    function saySomething(txt){
        alert(txt);
    };
</script>
```

Additional Information:

Web Application running on .NET 4.0
Language: C#

Update:

After working with this a while, I've determined that you can't use `<%%>` tags in ASP controls. Additionally, if you're looking for dynamic evaluation of control values AVOID AVOID AVOID using `<%=someControl.Text%>` or similar constructs since they are only evaluated once a request is submitted to the server. If you need a static value from another control at runtime, simply set that value in the page load event or handle it another way in the code behind.

Comment: View the page source, it will show you the problem!

Comment: See my updated answer - it's because you're trying to use inline code in a server control...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put `'` around your text in the `saySomething()` call.

Like this:

```
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSaySomething1" Text="Say Something" OnClientClick="saySomething('<%=txtToSay.Text%>');"  />
```

**UPDATE**

`<%= %>` won't work inside an asp.net control. Can you set it from the code-behind?

I.E

```
btnSaySomething1.OnClientClick = "Text to say"
```

Comment: Doing that passes the value `<%=txtToSay.Text%>` to the function - I've already tried that approach.

Comment: No, you need to wrap `<%=txtToSay.Text%>` in quotes - like in my answer, so it's `'<%=txtToSay.Text%>'` - notice the single `'` quote around it

Comment: you have the same difference between your working and not working code. Working has it wrapped `'something'`

Comment: Like I said, I've tried that approach. Look at my updated question. I've used `OnClientClick="saySomething('<%=txtToSay.Text%>');"` and it passes in `<%=txtToSay.Text%>` as the value to the function.

Comment: Ahh... it's because it's in an asp:button... updating answer

Comment: I can set it on the Page_Load event, but then it is basically just a server side event. I can write handlers to do it with pure Javascript, however. I was just surprised that it didn't work.

Comment: Yep, it's because the button is rendered before the inline stuff. Either that or change it from a server control. However, this is the problem as mentioned in the answer :)

Comment: I'll give you the points for the answer, but see my update on the question. It makes more sense when I think about it from that point of view. I was trying to make a square peg fit in a round hole and that always causes problems.

Comment: Many thanks. and yep, that about sums it up nicely. Ultimately, it's a server control and needs it's properties etc setting before it's rendered.

Answer (score 2):

`Javacript will search for variable name = txtToSay.Text` in saySomething function call, Put quotes around it to make it string value

Change

```
OnClientClick="saySomething(<%=txtToSay.Text%>);"
```

To

```
OnClientClick="saySomething('<%=txtToSay.Text%>');"
```

You can get the txtToSay.Text without passing it this way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function saySomething(txt){
        alert(document.getElementById('<%=txtToSay.Text%>').value);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Doing that passes the value `<%=txtToSay.Text%>` to the function - I've already tried that approach.

Comment: This approach does work, but I already knew it. I'm finding it curious that the value of `txtToSay` isn't being passed into the function from the OnClientClick call.

Comment: Can you pass ClientID to make sure our syntax is correct OnClientClick="saySomething('<%=txtToSay.ClientID%>');"

Comment: Sure thing - I got the same result. The value that gets passed to the function is: `<%=txtToSay.ClientID%>`.